# How to print a bill after swapping a credit card from Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am coding for a project like credit card swipping and get a bill..They are using two portable printers easy to get a bill while delivery..After he enters the amount and i need to connect to the webserver and get bill for that .The bill has to be print from the portablr printers.How to get printing option from the portable printer.I searched for that and it is saying that apple will support only Hp printers. I need to get get the print what ever the printer is .Any own can share the code or Share me if any third party api is there.ThanksInAdvance .Get the print is the problem..

Comment: Feel like writing some drivers?

Comment: hmm to print that perticular bill

Comment: The problem isn't getting the data, it's getting Apple's device to tell the printer how to print that data. That's where the driver comes in. If it isn't supported by Apple, your out of luck, unless you feel like writing a driver for that particular printer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Jailbreak the device and write your own printer drives and all that "fun" stuff.

   This option really isn't that great.  It means you'll have gobs and gobs of extra work to do, reverse engineering the printing frameworks, figuring out what all the private API is, how to use it, what to do when things go wrong, etc.  This will be hundreds of man-hours of work.  I absolutely do not recommend going this route.
2. Use an AirPrint-enabled printer.

   AirPrint is a technology that was created by Apple and is licensed for free to printer manufacturers.  There are many manufacturers that are including AirPrint compatibility in their newest printers.  If you're using an AirPrint printer, then printing is a simple matter of bringing up the `UIPrintInteractionController` and letting it do its thing.  You'll need to actually generate content to print, but that can be as simple as passing a `UIImage` in or giving it a string of markup.  If you want to do something more custom than that, you'll create a custom `UIPrintPageRenderer` subclass.  For more information, check out Session 108 from WWDC 2011.